Make picture carousel responsive
I'm using a picture carousel I found on the internet in my website, but i'm having the hardest time making it responsive.
Here's the Codepen link to the example project:
<https://codepen.io/RaduBratan/pen/dyGEzay>

It looks great on a computer screen, for which it is obviously intended, but I obviously would want it to work on a phone as well! I've been working with media queries to rearrange the objects for smaller screens, but I can't completely figure out how to get it one. What I want is the text on top, the picture below that, and the navigation arrows on the bottom.
Any hints on how to do that?
Despite my best efforts, I can't figure out how to get the navigation arrows at the bottom, and so the background colour generated by the JS script doesn't go all the way through behind the picture as well.
Much obliged to anyone who can give some pointers.
Needless to say, I'm quite new at this ;-)

Post code as a [mcve] (hint: click the brackets button <>).
